# Are questions about a specific feature implementation of an Open-Source framework on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

It is not rare to see questions of the following shape in some tags:

> The open-source framework Kittenz can do [some specific cool stuff].
>   How can it do [that specific cool stuff]?

Are questions like this on-topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: They're likely to be too broad

Comment: actually I consider "specific feature implementation" is different from "specific cool stuff"

Answer (score 7):

## Multiple justifiable reasons to close

That exact question would be considered too broad since it is not asking anything specifically. Instead it is suggesting we lay out the how the feature works or link to an external site. Neither of those options would fly for something like [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) so that question should be down-voted and subsequently removed.

<strike>Cool would be opinionated since I think bagels are cool but others don't. Obviously I would expect real questions not to be phrased as such. Just trying to make a point with that type of sentence.</strike>

">How can it do [that specific cool stuff]" also has a specific close reason

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

## At the end of the day

As long as there is a **specific programming related question**, that is on-topic here, the subject can easily be about Open-Source frameworks.

The only potential risk is that no one is versed in using it.

Comment: Sorry, I should stop lacking seriousness in my questions. It was unclear, I have edited the question. [cool stuff] defines some kind of specific feature (data-binding, templating, coffee-brewing, ...)

Comment: @Kyll I'm sorry for putting that comment in my post about the "cool". It was more meant as a comical aside. I think the jist of my post still stands. "How do I do this" or "what can I do with this" is what I read and responded too.

Comment: Ah, sorry for taking it first-degree. Your post does stand very well. If no other answer is posted in the couple days I will add a green makeup.

Answer (score 0):

There's a strong feeling in the SO community that you must show that you have tried, then ask question resulting from your efforts.

"*How do I make this feature*" wouldn't fall under that category unless it was something very specific.

There is a [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE site, which could be a good place to ask "*I've done this, would there of been a better way?*" type questions.

Would there be room for an Open Source Collaboration SE?

Comment: For emphasis: Good guess is that the question as stated by the OP would _not_ be on-topic for Code Review

Comment: I probably agree, but it might be easier to work it into an acceptable question?