# Is asking for help on how to debug "how long does npx take to run" allowed?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I was experiencing performance issues and don't know what to look for, or test, in order to debug the performance issues. So in [Why does npx --help take >3 seconds to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77950720/why-does-npx-help-take-3-seconds-to-execute) I asked for an answer or any advice on where to look or how to profile the issue. I tried my best to add relevant information such as program versions and timing outputs. However now it's been downvoted and voted to be closed by 2 people. Also, the part where I asked for advice on how to debug this issue got removed in an edit.

Is it not allowed to ask for advice on *how* to debug an issue?

What else made my question wrong and voted to be closed?

Comment: If anything, the close reason chosen by the two votes thus far is quite a stretch.

Comment: The "*Any help or comments on what I can try would be greatly appreciated!*"  was appropriately removed as this text is fluff that adds nothing to the question as it provides no information that is used to fully understand your problem. The site is not for personal help but rather for providing specific questions and answers for future visitors with similar problems. That many get personal help using the site is a beneficial side effect, but again is not its main purpose. Broad questions that ask for general guidance are off-topic.

Comment: possibly related? in that you're asking why a method of an open source tool is slow? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305962/are-questions-about-a-specific-feature-implementation-of-an-open-source-framewor

Comment: There was no question in that post. There was a question in the title. Don't put something only in the title. The situation described in the title was more specific than what you seemed likely to be trying to ask given the 1st sentence. Moreover contrary to this meta post it has never asked "how to debug".

Comment: I understand that @HovercraftFullOfEels, and I can see how the sentence could seem like "fluff". It wasn't the best formulation. The message I tried to convey was that I would appreciate advice on how I could move forward and attempt to find the root cause of the problem. Would that also be considered fluff, if it were formulated better?

Comment: Again, whether you appreciate more advice is irrelevant. The crux of the question is the question itself, not what you do or do not appreciate. I'm not trying to be harsh, but the site isn't a forum. You ask a clear and specific question and your question text should support that most specific question. That's it.

Comment: @philipxy I saw the latest edits you added to the original question, thank you. My question was quite poorly formulated, I see that now, however in this meta post I equated " I don't know where to start profiling this or finding out the root cause. Any help or comments on what I can try would be greatly appreciated!" to "How to debug" in short here. I'm starting conclude that my post was just imprecisely formulated and that's why it was deleted. "not about programming or software development" is a bit of a stretch though...

Comment: I think it’s pretty telling that now that you found `—verbose`, *you still don’t consider the question answered*. This is pretty much what the question asked for (advice for debugging) but it still cannot answer the question because the question isn’t focused on a clear issue. Rather it would be a guesswork of a myriad of things one *might* check. Such questions aren’t useful to others with similar problems (as it is impossible to tell if they actually have the same problem) nor are they properly answerable (as they are a grab bag for "try this" guesses).

Answer (score 14):

If you can provide an MRE, just about any debugging question is fair game.

If all you have is a symptom, that isn’t a good fit for the site. There is a myriad of things that could be issues, and a myriad of things that could help debugging these.
Other people looking for solutions won’t know whether they have the same problem underlying the symptom. People looking to answer are left with guessing blindly or giving generic advice.

What you need is someone to debug this *with* you, not the asynchronous Q&A for reusable knowledge that SO is striving for.